# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token after build

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, build, bootstrap-vue

Some **special characters** appears in the build of my app and trigger a SyntaxError after the build.
Example of special characters: ���s�J����Ln�̧�e"X���;R�ɸ��
It's also difficult to describe since it appears randomly and the position of the error in the code is random too.

I can't figure out why I have this error...

[here is an example of what I can see when I click on the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQB8S.jpg)

Comment: Is it binary? If yes you should convert to text first.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer :/
What is binary?

Comment: Those look like [unicode replacement characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) which means that there appears to be an invalid unicode character at that point. This usually happens when you send the data in a non-unicode format and attempt to interpret that as unicode. Read [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for more ideas on what you can try to do